# Grouped boxplot from multiple DataFrames

Tags: pandas, boxplot, seaborn

I have two DataFrames with the same rows but containing different values.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'label_id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    'value1': [3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'label_id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    'value2': [4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3]})
```

Is there a way to create a boxplot with `x='label_id'` and `hue='value*'`? By that I mean that the boxplots should be grouped by the originating DataFrame.

I thought about combining `df1` and `df2` into a single DataFrame, but I'm not sure if the new DataFrame should be of the form

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label_id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   'value1': [3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 8],
                   'value2': [4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3]})
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label_id': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   'value': [3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 8, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3],
                   'origin': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
```

and what the simplest way of achieving this would be. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should use option 2.

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks! Turns out this was simple in the end and I was almost there already.